# query false but performs query

Tags: php, mysqli

I have this query that works fine in other parts of the same website, but I am run in to a problem where the check says isn't true but it actually performs correctly?

```
<?php

    $conn = new mysqli($mysql_host, $mysql_user, $mysql_password, $mysql_database);
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM Stock WHERE StockItemID='12'";
    $result = $conn->query($sql) or die( $conn->connect_error );
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();

    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
         echo $row['StockCategory'];
    } else {
         printf("Errorcode: %d\n", $conn->errno);
    }
    $conn->close();
?>
```

Because in my above example I didn't get the echo, I thought it hadn't worked but I get back - Errorcode: 0

But the kicker is that if I echo out a value from the table it works.

Comment: use the proper checking accordingly, excerpts from the manual: `Returns FALSE on failure. For successful SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE or EXPLAIN queries mysqli_query() will return a mysqli_result object. For other successful queries mysqli_query() will return TRUE.`

Comment: Thanks heaps, Ghost. I can't find where I give you a thumbs up or how to mark this now as answered but all three inputs on this thread helped heaps.

Comment: if those answers below helped you, accept it by clicking the check mark on the lefthand side, you can only accept one answer, just use your best judgement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select queries return a resultset

```
$conn = new mysqli($mysql_host, $mysql_user, $mysql_password, $mysql_database);
if ($conn->connect_error) { die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error); } 
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Stock WHERE StockItemID='12'";
$result = $conn->query($sql) or die( $conn->connect_error );
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
    echo $row['StockCategory'];
} else {
    printf("Errorcode: %d\n", $conn->errno);
}
$conn->close();
```

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

Comment: Hey thanks, vibol. You made that too easy with your code. Cut and pasted it and off she went, worked beautifully. Also thanks for the link, now I think I get it - cheers.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see whether your query returned a row, then *check that row itself*.

Yes, as simple and as logical as that.

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
$conn = new mysqli($mysql_host, $mysql_user, $mysql_password, $mysql_database);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Stock WHERE StockItemID='12'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
if ($row) { // here
    echo $row['StockCategory']; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, 'Your Common Sense'. I think I lack logical but obviously have plenty of simple. Your input helped a lot, it's appreciated.